# JEST - Yellow lines on the coverage report for async methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following case on Vue JS, in a method inside a component:
[image]

The method `loadProducts` is async, when I run the JEST tests, shows me I don't cover line 320, but all other lines and inside the function are covered.

If I tried to await and evaluate the result of this function I will receive the result of line 339 and 343:
`const {success} = await wrapper.vm.loadProducts();`

A simplified test that I wrote:

```
describe('loadProducts', () => {
  it('should return false', async () => {
    const {success} = await wrapper.vm.loadProducts();

    expect(success).toEqual(false);
  });
);
```

How can I avoid the coverage report shows me this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess - maybe you should render the component that is using that function and make it run that function. I cannot tell when that function is called, maybe on some button click? Then render the component and click the button in the test.

You can always check the coverage report which should be under the `./coverage/lcov-report/index.html`. You can find there sometimes some additional information.

BTW: Your `then` returns `success` in Pascalcase and the catch in lowercase.